# Node-Red Log data to CSV

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to log data from multiple Modbus TCP connections into a CSV file on my local hard drive.

My set up currently is as follows:

[image]

I am struggling with the modify payload part!

I am unsure what to write in the function.... I would like a format like this, with values corresponding with each variable:

```
Time,STBD Bus Volts,Var2,Var3......VarX
yyyymmddHHMMSS,1.5,y,z,q,.......,r
```

etc. I hope that is clear enough.

NB: I know I have only shown one Modbus input thus far, I will add more, I would like to understand how to write the functions.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: As a tip, the CSV node works both ways, if you feed it a CSV file it will generate a JSON object, which will match the required input to generate the CSV

Comment: @hardillb TO be honest I haven't because I am unsure where to start..... I was wondering can I reference the Modbus intput by the topic name I have assigned it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node-red output a message to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089644/node-red-output-a-message-to-csv)